Words That Have the Form A-B-A
I do not know the term for words like this, but an example is ABRA-CAD-ABRA. Are there words like this in the English language? Also, what is the term for this kind of word (if any)?
To clarify based off of the comments and to narrow the search; We have a starting set of characters A, which have at least 3 letters. Then we have a middle set of characters B, which have at least 1 letter. Then the final word consists of A followed by B and then again followed by B.

You mean a word with a letter or multiple letters repeated in the same order at start and end, like tomato (TO-MA-TO)?

I would suggest that there aren't a huge number, but because the last letters generally have an entirely different function from the first (eg deride) categorising these words isn't particularly useful.

@StuartF Yes exactly! The more symmetric the A's are, the better :)

@AndrewLeach If you mean to tell me, that there hasn't been historically a use case for it, therefore no one has categorized it, that could make sense. But if you mean to say there is no reason at all, I do not know that beforehand. Maybe there are sub-categories of these words that are interesting to study :)

I believe this question belongs on Puzzling.SE (it's unlikely there will be a standard term for such words), as it's more trivia- than truly morphologically orientated.

There are thousands of such words, simply because there are tons of words that start and end with the same letter. If you require each part to be over one letter long and no hyphens, there are still hundreds.

abracadabra
ickylickysticky
muckamuck
overcover
overrecover
Shahanshah
shipmanship
sterraster
taratantara
trinitrin
undergrounder
uricosuric
wishtonwish

Taking the list of words at https://github.com/dwyl/english-words there seem to be 271 examples, though I am not sure the original list is reliable and whether all of these would always be counted as words. For example, what does fiftyty-fifty mean and should it be fifty-fifty?
  [1] "abracadabra"            "aftershaft"            
  [3] "airy-fairy"             "air-to-air"            
  [5] "antiagglutinant"        "anticipant"            
  [7] "anticoagulant"          "anticonvulsant"        
  [9] "antidepressant"         "anti-depressant"       
 [11] "antidetonant"           "antifoggant"           
 [13] "antiformant"            "antioxidant"           
 [15] "antiozonant"            "antiperspirant"        
 [17] "antipredeterminant"     "antiradiant"           
 [19] "antistimulant"          "antsy-pantsy"          
 [21] "archmonarch"            "archpatriarch"         
 [23] "archphylarch"           "argy-bargy"            
 [25] "argle-bargle"           "argue-bargue"          
 [27] "arm-in-arm"             "arsy-varsy"            
 [29] "astroblast"             "autojuggernaut"        
 [31] "back-to-back"           "bedaubed"              
 [33] "bedumbed"               "beglerbeg"             
 [35] "benzeneazobenzene"      "bid-a-bid"             
 [37] "biddy-bid"              "bit-by-bit"            
 [39] "blankety-blank"         "bleachable"            
 [41] "blow-by-blow"           "calelectrical"         
 [43] "calendrical"            "caliological"          
 [45] "calisthenical"          "calligraphical"        
 [47] "calorifical"            "calorimetrical"        
 [49] "cha-cha-cha"            "chest-on-chest"        
 [51] "chucky-chuck"           "chute-the-chute"       
 [53] "cinchonicin"            "clickety-click"        
 [55] "clinkety-clink"         "collar-to-collar"      
 [57] "cone-in-cone"           "convexo-convex"        
 [59] "day-by-day"             "day-to-day"            
 [61] "desuetudes"             "dog-eat-dog"           
 [63] "door-to-door"           "dos-a-dos"             
 [65] "east-northeast"         "east-southeast"        
 [67] "eentsy-weentsy"         "eyeball-to-eyeball"    
 [69] "eighty-eight"           "end-to-end"            
 [71] "entablement"            "entailment"            
 [73] "entalent"               "entanglement"          
 [75] "entassment"             "entertainment"         
 [77] "enthrallment"           "enthralment"           
 [79] "enthronement"           "enticement"            
 [81] "entitlement"            "entoilment"            
 [83] "entombment"             "entonement"            
 [85] "entrainment"            "entrancement"          
 [87] "entrapment"             "entreatment"           
 [89] "entrenchment"           "entrustment"           
 [91] "entwinement"            "ern-fern"              
 [93] "essentialness"          "even-steven"           
 [95] "face-to-face"           "fiftyty-fifty"         
 [97] "five-by-five"           "full-to-full"          
 [99] "galangal"               "gentleman-agent"       
[101] "get-up-and-get"         "gogmagog"              
[103] "goody-good"             "ground-to-ground"      
[105] "half-and-half"          "hand-in-hand"          
[107] "hand-to-hand"           "hawkshaw"              
[109] "heart-to-heart"         "heresiographer"        
[111] "hose-in-hose"           "hot-shot"              
[113] "house-to-house"         "yackety-yack"          
[115] "yakety-yak"             "yakity-yak"            
[117] "yakkety-yak"            "yellowish-green-yellow"
[119] "yellowish-red-yellow"   "ingathering"           
[121] "ingeminating"           "ingenerating"          
[123] "ingesting"              "ingiving"              
[125] "inglobing"              "ingoting"              
[127] "ingrafting"             "ingraining"            
[129] "ingratiating"           "ingrossing"            
[131] "ingrowing"              "ingulfing"             
[133] "ingurgitating"          "insulins"              
[135] "interpoint"             "ionisation"            
[137] "isthmist"               "itsy-bitsy"            
[139] "itsy-witsy"             "itty-bitty"            
[141] "jib-o-jib"              "kingmaking"            
[143] "little-by-little"       "loop-the-loop"         
[145] "maharmah"               "mangleman"             
[147] "man-to-man"             "man-woman"             
[149] "mastocarcinomas"        "mesdames"              
[151] "mesosomes"              "meter-millimeter"      
[153] "microchemic"            "microcosmic"           
[155] "microeconomic"          "microphthalmic"        
[157] "microseismic"           "microsomic"            
[159] "microthermic"           "microtomic"            
[161] "mouth-to-mouth"         "nicotinic"             
[163] "nighty-night"           "ninety-nine"           
[165] "okeydoke"               "okey-doke"             
[167] "okle-dokle"             "old-gold"              
[169] "one-by-one"             "one-to-one"            
[171] "opeidoscope"            "out-and-out"           
[173] "outscout"               "outshout"              
[175] "outspout"               "overdrove"             
[177] "overlove"               "overprove"             
[179] "overstrove"             "overwove"              
[181] "person-to-person"       "phycography"           
[183] "phyllomorphy"           "phylography"           
[185] "physicophilosophy"      "physiography"          
[187] "physiophilosophy"       "physiosophy"           
[189] "phytogeography"         "phytography"           
[191] "phytotopography"        "pimperlimpimp"         
[193] "play-by-play"           "point-to-point"        
[195] "portal-to-portal"       "potent-counterpotent"  
[197] "psychoepilepsy"         "psycholepsy"           
[199] "ramble-scramble"        "rasboras"              
[201] "red-collared"           "red-colored"           
[203] "reddish-colored"        "reddish-haired"        
[205] "red-eared"              "redeclared"            
[207] "redelivered"            "red-feathered"         
[209] "red-figured"            "red-flowered"          
[211] "red-haired"             "rediscovered"          
[213] "red-lettered"           "red-shouldered"        
[215] "red-tempered"           "red-trousered"         
[217] "red-upholstered"        "reel-to-reel"          
[219] "rescores"               "respires"              
[221] "restores"               "restructures"          
[223] "rixatrix"               "salpingonasal"         
[225] "self-counsel"           "sermoniser"            
[227] "seventy-seven"          "shibuichi-doshi"       
[229] "shipmanship"            "shirakashi"            
[231] "side-by-side"           "six-by-six"            
[233] "six-o-six"              "sixty-six"             
[235] "starosta"               "station-to-station"    
[237] "step-by-step"           "such-and-such"         
[239] "surface-to-surface"     "talky-talk"            
[241] "tap-tap-tap"            "taratantara"           
[243] "tat-tat-tat"            "tessellates"           
[245] "testates"               "tete-a-tete"           
[247] "thymopathy"             "through-and-through"   
[249] "tick-a-tick"            "tink-a-tink"           
[251] "tongue-wanton"          "tormentor"             
[253] "toxin-anatoxin"         "toxin-antitoxin"       
[255] "tum-ti-tum"             "tzaritza"              
[257] "underbound"             "underground"           
[259] "undergrounder"          "under-round"           
[261] "undersound"             "underwound"            
[263] "uricosuric"             "vis-a-vis"             
[265] "wall-to-wall"           "west-northwest"        
[267] "west-north-west"        "west-southwest"        
[269] "west-south-west"        "wishtonwish"           
[271] "word-for-word"    

 


This is great, thank you! Especially man-wo-man is a good one, haha.
